# Virtual directory under sharepoint site

Tags: iis

We have read-only content which is basically on network share. I'd like to be able to display it in my sharepoint site and be able to access it without sharepoint as well, so I created virtual directory under IIS which maps to my content.

The problem is that when I access it like http://sp1/myContent, it says Access Denied. And when I'm logged off, it tries to authenticate me. I have anonymous access activated on my site and I have no clue how to skip this.

### **EDIT:**

I found this in my ProcMon log:

```
12:57:26,7875600    w3wp.exe    7940    CreateFile  \\VAP1\FTP\ ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Sequential Access, Attributes: RE, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, Impersonating: NT AUTHORITY\IUSR  DOMAIN\spcontent
```

So maybe it's due the fact that it tries to connect as **IUSR**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your app pool account have access to the networked information?

It's worth checking IIS log files to see exactly what's being requested.

A tool such as [SysInternals Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is very useful for determining what access problems are occurring within an application.  I'd recommend firing it up when you make the request and seeing what context the content is being requested under.

Comment: Yes, this content is available for application pool identity. I'll check logs and get back.

Comment: Edited question with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may want to consider if you haven't already is the use of the page viewer web part. You can expose file shares through this and it provides a fairly good interface for doing so.

http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2007/11/29/displaying-a-file-or-a-folder-in-the-page-viewer.aspx

Comment: Looks promising, and worth a try but I also need that those resources are available by browser itself, by specifying uri - that's why try to use virtual directory.

Comment: Is this for access off the network that the file share is on? Otherwise why not just use the UNC path? \\fileserver\share\folder\file.doc

Comment: I want it to be readable from Internet for users who memorized link for example, outside my domain.

Comment: Gotcha. The virtual directory makes sense then.